# Why can host not access dockerised mongodb using localhost

Tags: linux, docker, mongodb

My mongodb container runs successfully.

However my host cannot access it using `localhost:27017` or `127.0.0.1:27017` or `0.0.0.0:27017`. I need to run `docker inspect ...` to discover the hostname.

- Why does it work this way?
- Is it possible to set it up so I can access it using `localhost`? Is that a good/bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

(sorry cannot add comments)

You could add a host name which map to your docker machine IP. e.g:

```
192.168.99.100 localhost
```

(considering `192.168.99.100` is the IP of your docker machine)

Else you can have a look at this (haven't tried myself):

[Using localhost for accessing containers](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-localhost-for-to-access-running-container/3148/6)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to hardcode it because then I'd have to change it every time. Also that post refers to running in a VM (I'm not). I can't find info that explains why this problem occurs.

Comment: Ah, i'm still using the legacy docker and still learning it, can't answer that, maybe look at bridging the network or something related.

Comment: Yeah when things don't work you need to try every trick in the book! :)